# SAP BW data integration with Snowflake

Tags: ssis, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sap-bw

Is there anyway to get the data and connect directly to Snowflake without any third party or open source software?

Our current setup is getting the data from SAP BW into DATAMART and then it is used by PowerBI.

We have a client request to do assessment for moving the data from SAP BW to Snowflake directly cause after research I found that Snowflake doesn't allow a direct connection with SAP or OData data sources.

Is there any recommendation or concerns in going with this approach?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The only data ingestion capabilities Snowflake has is to bulk load from files held on a cloud platform (S3, Azure Blob, etc.).

If you can't, or don't want to, get your data into one of these file stores then you'd need to use a commercial ETL tool or "roll your own" solution using e.g. Python